# jQuery Validation plugin - validate a mix of radio and checkbox inputs with Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate

On `$(document).ready`, the submit button is disabled. The button should be enabled only when the entire form is valid, i.e. 1) one radio (fruit) is selected, and 2) one or more checkboxes (occasions) are selected. I have looked at many answers here, and tried using function that tests `if (form.valid())` on document change, but that evaluates to `true` when only the fruit is selected. I believe that the `submitHandler` is what I want to get at the whole form, but it's not firing. Changing the radios into checkboxes doesn't make a difference.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bahmait/gcpv9p82/)**

html

```
<form id="categorizer-form" method="POST" action="\submit">
    <div class="container">
        <br><p>1. What <strong>kind</strong> of fruit is this?</p>
        <div class="btn-group col-xs-12" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="kind" id="apple" value="apple">apple
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="kind" id="orange" value="orange">orange
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <br><p>2. On what <strong>meal occasions</strong> would you eat it? (Please choose as many as apply.)</p>
        <div class="btn-group col-xs-12" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="checkbox" name="occasion" id="breakfast" value="breakfast" >breakfast
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="checkbox" name="occasion" id="lunch" value="lunch" >lunch
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="checkbox" name="occasion" id="dinner" value="dinner" >dinner
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="checkbox" name="occasion" id="snack" value="snack" >snack
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ######################### -->
<br>
<br>
    <div class="well well2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                    <button class='btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-next' type='submit' id='Next'>Click to submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.btn-next').attr('disabled', true)

    $( 'form#categorizer-form' ).validate({
        debug: true,
        rules: {
            kind: {
                required: true,
            },
            occasion: {
                required: true,
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('submitHandler fired')
            $('.btn-next').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success');        // enables button
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcpv9p82/7/). The only weird thing I see is that "This field is required" is not in proper place.

Comment: Is it not firing in fiddle, or in your code? It works in fiddle for me (`alert('hi')` is fired and button becomes green). Maybe two lost `;` cause problems... I added them in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcpv9p82/10/).

Comment: Weird. That fiddle (v10) not working for me as described in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.

Comment: I have tested it in Chrome 37.0.2062.124, in Opera 24.0 and in Firefox 31.0 - it works. I actually even don't know what to suggest in this situation.

Comment: Are there any errors in console?

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: Works for me (the fiddle)

Comment: The `submitHandler` fires for me.  OP, please provide code that demonstrates this problem.

Comment: @Regent, maybe it would be better to turn the button green _before_ you click it.  http://jsfiddle.net/xgb64b4p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    alert('submitted')
    $('.btn-next').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success'); // enables button
}
```

The `submitHandler` will only fire when both of these conditions are met...

1. The user clicks the submit button.
2. The form is valid.

Your `submitHandler` is not firing because your submit button is disabled and cannot be clicked.  You cannot enable the submit button within the `submitHandler` because you have no way to trigger it without clicking the button.

Instead, you must enable the submit button outside of the `submitHandler` by using a `change` event handler, external to the `.validate()` method, that fires every time the form changes.  Then you can use the `.valid()` method to test the form and decide if the button can be enabled.

```
$('#categorizer-form').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        // enable button
        $('.btn-next').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success'); 
    } else {
        // disable button        
        $('.btn-next').prop('disabled', true).addClass('btn-danger').removeClass('btn-success'); 
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/h1r2fmj0/**

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"... tried using function that tests `if (form.valid())` on document change, but that evaluates to true when only the fruit is selected."*

*That is impossible*, unless you somehow attached `.valid()` to the fruit field.   Otherwise, when properly attached to the `<form>` element, `.valid()` can only return `true` when the *whole form* is valid.

In other words, `form.valid()` is meaningless, unless you've already defined `var form = $('#categorizer-form')`.

It must be attached to a variable or selector that targets the `<form>` element.  Depending on how/where you used it, the `form` keyword may not work.  (The `form` keyword is only for use inside of certain callback functions like `submitHandler`.  However, you normally would **not** use the `.valid()` method *anywhere* inside of the `.validate()` method.)

Notice in the demo code above where `$(this).valid()` is the same as `$('#categorizer-form').valid()`, because `$(this)` represents `$('#categorizer-form')`.

---

*You need to show us the code that is causing the problem you describe.*

Comment: Yes, it looks more user-friendly, +1

Comment: @Regent got me to the solution in chat. Fiddle was working (then and now). I wasn't clicking because button was remaining red. Thank you for this, Sparky. Your other posts have also helped me a great deal.